# How to show elliptic curve endomorphism is commutative?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

> For an elliptic curve $E/k$, let $\alpha$ be any endomorphism over
>   $\bar{k}$ in End($E$) and let $[n]$ be the multiplication-by-$n$
>   endomorphism. Show that $[n] \bullet \alpha=\alpha \bullet [n]$, i.e.,
>   $[n]$ is commutative with all endomorphisms.

So we have that $[n] : E \rightarrow E$ is given by $P \rightarrow nP$ is an endomorphism defined over the given space but what's the easiest way to show that $[n]$ is commutative with all endomorphisms?

Comment: Isn't an endomorphism of elliptic curves always a $\;\Bbb Z-$ module homomorphism? In this case it follows at once that $\;\alpha(nP)=n\alpha(P)\iff [n]\alpha=\alpha[n]\;$ .

Comment: Why is an endomorphism of elliptic curves always a $\mathbb{Z}$ module homomorphism?

Comment: I think that is part of the definition.

Comment: If $\alpha \in End(E)$ then $\forall P,P' \in E, \alpha(P+P') = \alpha(P)+\alpha(P')$ and hence $$\alpha ([n] P) = \alpha ([n-1] P)+\alpha(P) = \alpha ([n-2] P)+[2]\alpha(P) = \ldots = \alpha([0]P) + [n] \alpha(P) =[n] \alpha(P)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, an endomorphism of a complex elliptic curve $E$ is a holomorphic map $E\rightarrow E$, which fixes the origin. It turns out that this condition is enough to force it to be a homomorphism of abelian
groups in the usual sense, i.e., it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism.

This definition makes sense for every algebraically closed field $k$, replacing "holomorphic" by "algebraic". Then we have

*Theorem:* Let $\phi\colon E(k)\rightarrow E(k)$ be an algebraic map, i.e., given by rational functions. Then $\phi$ is a group endomorphism if and only if $\phi$ fixes the origin.